# Using InStr to find the first occurence that isn't a certain character

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm trying to use InStr to find the first character that isn't a "0" (starting from the left-hand side) in strings like this:

```
000000000001
000000004092
000000000052
000000001006
```

Can this be done with InStr, or should I use something different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for an index of an item that is not zero (that may also be a non-digit) use this regular expression: `[^0]`

```
Dim pos as Integer = Regex.Match(str, "[^0]").Index
```

Keep in mind, Regex functions require the following library call:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

This will not work well when the string is composed entirely of zeros, so you may want to modify the expression to allow zero to be the last (or the only) character in the string:

```
`([^0])|(0$)`
          ^--- This meta-character matches an end-of-string marker
```

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my comment because I forgot the .Index portion.  It does indeed work, like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using VB.**NET** you should use .NET methods.

One way is using  `Enumerable.Where` which is a `Linq` method:

```
Dim value = "000000000001"
Dim firstNotZero = From c In value Where c <> "0"c
If firstNotZero.Any Then
    Dim first As Char = firstNotZero.First
End If
```

**Edit**: If you don't want to use Linq or Regex, you can also use a simple loop:

```
Dim lines = {"000000000001", "000000004092", "000000000052", "000000001006"}
Dim firstDigits As New List(Of Char)
For Each line In lines
    For Each c In line
        If c <> "0"c Then
            firstDigits.Add(c)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

This adds all first not 0 characters to a `List(Of Char)`.

Comment: I'm not real familiar with LINQ, is there any other way using .NET methods to do it?  I like to be able to understand my code when I go back through and look at it.

Comment: @TaylorKimmel: most people would use the regex approach from dasblinkenlight or slaks. I've just added linq because it might be easier to understand. It's basically a loop over chars in a string.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha.  I normally prefer .NET methods, but in this case the Regex function is more understandable to me.  Thanks anyhow.

Comment: @TaylorKimmel: Added a simple loop approach.

Comment: Yeah, I knew before I asked this question how to convert the string to a character array and do a For...Each loop.  I just wanted something that would fit on a single line (so I could use it in a Mid Function).

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions:

```
Regex.Match(yourString, "[1-9]")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "negate" the parameters of `InStr`.

If you know the input, you can simply search for what should not there (possibly using regex).

It is difficult to give you something less general as an answer without details such as - what is the range of input characters? What rules govern a match? How is this to be used?